# Woocommerce category page custom sort Products

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to sort products on category page. My products are in 3 subcategories i want to sort by categories like on first i want to show products start with "Bio Keratin" 2nd product start with "Bio Keratin Luxury" and last i want to show products start with "Bio Keratin Botanical"

```
function custom_product_ordering( $sort_args ) {
    $sort_args['orderby'] = 'title';
    $sort_args['order'] = 'ASC'; // You can change to 'DESC' if needed

    // Define custom sorting order based on product names
    $sort_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $sort_args['meta_key'] = '_prefix_sort_order'; // Create a custom field '_prefix_sort_order'

    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_product_ordering' );

// Update the products with a sorting order based on the prefix
function update_product_prefix_sort_order() {
    $product_ids = wc_get_products(
        array(
            'limit' => -1,
            'return' => 'ids',
        )
    );

    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        $product_name = get_the_title( $product_id );
        $sort_order = get_sort_order_from_product_name( $product_name );

        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_prefix_sort_order', $sort_order );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'update_product_prefix_sort_order' );

// Define a function to get the sorting order from the product name
function get_sort_order_from_product_name( $product_name ) {
    // Define your custom sorting logic here
    if ( strpos( $product_name, 'Bio Keratin Botanical' ) === 0 ) {
        return 3;
    } elseif ( strpos( $product_name, 'Bio Keratin Luxury' ) === 0 ) {
        return 2;
    } elseif ( strpos( $product_name, 'Bio Keratin' ) === 0 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 1; // Default sorting order if not matched
    }
}
```

i am using this code

i wan to sort products accordingly mention above